# Why, after I removed the extra code, the list of names is not displayed?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react application, the result of which is: a list of names that are displayed using the `fetch` method, which in turn takes data from a json file - which button is pressed from that array the data is taken(first or second) + there is a search filter by firstname.

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import TableData from "./TableData";
import TableSearch from "./TableSearch";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    filteredData: [],
    search: "",
    shift: "first"
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/data/today.json");
    const data = (await response.json()).group;

    this.setState(
      {
        data,
        shift: Object.keys(data)[0]
      },
      this.filter
    );
  };

  updateSearch = e => {
    this.setState({
      search: e.target.value
    });
  };

  filter = () => {
    this.setState(({ search, data, shift }) => {
      const s = search.toLowerCase();
      return {
        filteredData: data[shift].filter(n =>
          n.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(s)
        )
      };
    });
  };

  onClick = ({
    target: {
      dataset: { shift }
    }
  }) => {
    this.setState(() => ({ shift }), this.filter);
  };

  render() {
    const { search, shift, data, filteredData } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <TableSearch
          value={search}
          onChange={this.updateSearch}
          onSearch={this.filter}
        />
        {Object.keys(data).map(n => (
          <button
            data-shift={n}
            onClick={this.onClick}
            className={n === shift ? "active" : ""}
          >
            {n} shift
          </button>
        ))}
        <TableData data={filteredData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

But at the moment I need to simplify and reduce my application, since something needs to be change in the logic, so just the same, I need go to the initial version of the application.
I just need to leave a list of names on the screen, and remove the buttons and filter.

Well, I removed:

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import TableData from "./TableData";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/data/today.json");
    const data = (await response.json()).group;

    console.log(data);
    this.setState({
      data
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TableData data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

And the list is not displayed ...

I think maybe this has something to do with the filter, but I'm not sure.
How then can I write the code so that list name only is displayed without buttons and filters? But at the same time, I cannot modify the **TableData.js** file since in this tasks it is necessary for further manipulations with the code.Well, at least not much to change**TableData.js**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski, done, tell me how to fix my problem?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-frog-hfl4k

Comment: dont work: "data.map is not a function" TableData.js. I think it is possible to change a little file ```TableData.js``` please tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code `filteredData: data[shift]` and `shift: Object.keys(data)[0]`:

- `filteredData` is an array
- `data` is an object like `{first: [], second: []}`

So, in the shortened version, you have to use an array, e.g.:

```
<TableData data={Object.values(this.state.data)[0] || []} />
```

And fix your initial state to match the type:

```
state = {
  data: {}
}
```

Comment: I corrected as you said, but still does not work, please look in the sandbox that I did wrong. Says that a error in the ```TableData.js```Maybe something still needs to be changed in the ```TableData.js```?
https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-water-440m3

Comment: if you cannot update TableDate.js to handle undefined data, you can pass `{Object.values(this.state.data)[0] || []}` with empty array as the default

Comment: I think it is possible to change a little file ```TableData.js``` please tell me how?

Comment: I write: ```{Object.values(this.state.data)[0] || []}```
and then just headers without data
https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-water-440m3

Comment: maybe you could fix it in my sandbox to display the list? because I'm already confused

Comment: you are rendering 3 cells: `<td>{item.ID}</td>`, `term`, and `actual`. none of those exist in your json file => all are undefined => the table has 6 row, but 5 of them are empty... you need to render the properties from your actual data - https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-jang-pficq

Comment: but i only need to display specific properties such as name, id, and some others...That will be in the mix,and they can be 20-30, and I only need a few. How in my case without email and phone number?

Comment: you can use the same syntax as you used before. but YOU know what properties really exist and that YOU want to access. I don't, so I can't help you with that particular task :(